# How to float elements with different heights?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I'm working on a responsive webdesign that floats multiple items in 4 columns side by side. Those items have different heights and hence floating doesn't properly work.

This is what happens at the moment:

[image: floating wrong]

Any ideas on how to make the elements float like that:

[image: floating right]

I guess this should work with jQuery "masonry", right? However I'm working with Zepto.js and I guess a jQuery plugin wouldn't work.

Is there any pure CSS (CSS3) way to that? Some trick or so?

If this wouldn't work with pure CSS or with JS is it possible to do this:

[image: floating different]

Now the second row with elements 5, 6 and 7 is not "really" floating the way you would expect it but there is a hidden line-break (clearfix) inside.

Is there any way to that with pure CSS? E.g. use `nth-child(4n+4)` and a pseudo-selector like `:after` to apply a line-break with `content`?

Any ideas on that? Any clever tricks to make that work?

Comment: To do the second one without clearfixing, just put 1,2,3,4 in a container, and 5,6,7,8 in a container

Comment: some jquery plugins do work with Zepto. I can't speak for Masonry, but you could try it before dismissing it.

Comment: Some JS alternatives to masonry have emerged by now: https://github.com/attila/savvior and https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore

Answer (score 35, accepted):

you could just apply a clear to every fifth element to force it to start all the way at the left. I think it would look something like this in css3:

```
div#wrapper > *:nth-child(4n+1) {
   clear: both;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/zPGVT/)

Comment: Beautiful answer. I knew about the use of `clear: both`, but had no idea you could specify a repeating index formula for selecting the `nth-child` in CSS3. I hope you don't mind @PeterVR but I added a small demo jsFiddle.

Comment: This really Brilliant solution

Comment: If you're really working on a responsive design, then the number of elements in a row might not always be 4. In that case @my-head-hurts answer will be better suited.

Comment: @ArnoudSietsema  `inline-block` is fine indeed nowadays. You could however easily change the `(4n+1)` part inside a media-query as well...

Comment: Works great with Bootstrap!

Comment: It's a beautiful answer, the reason why inline-block sometimes apply bad in those situations is that you still have HTML spaces... you can still use comments in code to prevent these but Its not always trouble you want to get into with a huge list of items for example

Comment: I still see space between 1 and 5, and between 3 and 7. How to get rid of those spaces?

Answer (score 22):

As mentioned by @Arieljuod you can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`. The beauty of this is that it will work in all browsers (including IE7+ with the hack below) and is completely fluid:

```
div {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    *display: inline;
    *margin-right: 0.3em;
    *zoom: 1;
    ...   
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cRKpD/1/**

Comment: Adding a bottom margin helps prevent the boxes from sitting on top of one another with no spacing in between them when the browser is narrow. Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gnNTZ/

Comment: @MattCoughlin good call - I had not taken that into account! I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but someone just linked this question to another similar one and I realized this one misses the flexbox solution...
(which was not around when the question was asked).

Add the desired vendor prefixes and remove unnecessary in your CSS

```
.parent {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

<kbd>[example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/y7f5vakr/3/embedded/result/#Result)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

for the second option, instad of "float: left" use "display: inline-block", you can even combine that with a text-align: center to always fill 100% except the last line

for the first option you could put 1 and 5 in onw container, 2 and 6 on another, and so one, then you float those containers

Answer (score 0):

for the last one, you could surround each group of four with a container.  Then float the divs inside of the containers, if you don't want to or can't do this manually, you could probably do this easily with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**First option**

[CSS multi-column layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), once it's adequately standardized and supported, may offer a flexible way to do this.

The only other CSS solution that comes to mind, though it may not be adequately responsive, is to group the elements in column containers (1 and 5, then 2 and 6, then 3 and 7, then 4).

Aside from those two options, I believe JS is required.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but put 1 in an additional divider. Then put 7 in that divider (you will have to adjust the divider so that 7 appears below 1). Might be useful to use overflow:visible in this divider.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using jQuery like this:

```js
var max_height = divs_cnt = 0;

$("#holder .box").each(function() {
  if (divs_cnt % 4 == 0) {
    $(this).css("clear", "both");
  }
  if (max_height < $(this).height()) {
    $("#holder .box").height($(this).height());
  }
  max_height = $(this).height();
  divs_cnt ++;
})
```

```css
#holder{
   width:100%;
   border:1px dotted blue;
   display:inline-block;
}
.box{
   width:100px;
   height:150px;
   background-color:#CCC;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:45px;
   display:inline-block;
}
.one{
   background-color:#0F0;
   height:200px;
}

.two{
   background-color:#0FF;
}

.three{
   background-color:#00F;
}

.four{
   background-color:#FF0;
}

.five{
   background-color:#0a1;
}

.six{
   background-color:#ec5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
    <div class="box one">1</div>
    <div class="box two">2</div>
    <div class="box three">3</div>
    <div class="box four">4</div>
    <div class="box five">5</div>
    <div class="box six">6</div>
</div>
```