# CSS - divs - clear:none and float both left and right

Tags: css

Here is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pQ63V/2/

```
#div1 {
    background-color:red;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
#div2 {
    background-color:green;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
#div3 {
    background-color:blue;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
#div4 {
    background-color:cyan;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
#div5 {
    background-color:magenta;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
#div6 {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
```

**The snippet of the website I'm actually trying to edit is here:
http://www.luminescence.co.uk/testing/
As you can see, extending the div on the left allows divs to float on the right, extending the div on the right does NOT allow divs to float on the left**

I have divs with varying height and would like them to be able to float to the left of larger divs and to the right of larger divs.

As you can see in the example, the yellow div will not stay up with the div to the right (because the css is float:left; )

Is there a way to "float:both;" ?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [css (or js): How to float elements with different heights?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811858/css-or-js-how-to-float-elements-with-different-heights)

Comment: I don't understand what's the desired result. Can you make that point clearer ?

Comment: If you're open to javascript, [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) might be worth looking at.

Comment: I've extended my example - this is a snippet of the web page in question http://www.luminescence.co.uk/testing/ if you extend the div on the left, other divs appear on the right, but NOT vice versa!

Comment: You may want to investigate `using flexbox to achieve masonry-like effect` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919147/using-flexbox-to-get-pinterest-or-jquery-masonry-layout).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/DY8CT/

Arranging them into columns is really your best bet to get your desired result

```
#div1 { background-color:red; width:300px; height:100px; float:left; clear:none; }
#div2 { background-color:green; width:300px; height:50px; float:left; clear:none; }
#div3 { background-color:blue; width:300px; height:50px; float:left; clear:none; }
#div4 { background-color:cyan; width:300px; height:50px; float:left; clear:none; }
#div5 { background-color:magenta; width:300px; height:100px; float:left; clear:none; }
#div6 { background-color:yellow; width:300px; height:50px; float:left; clear:none; }

.col {background:none; width:300px; float:left;}
```

Comment: I could do this, however they are all divs that can be extended onclick and I'd like the user to be able to extend some and bump the others onto the left / right depending where the gap lies

Comment: I believe it is actually impossible to do what you want as floating divs unless there is something in css3 I don't know about. You can still get the functionality you want with columns and javascript.