# How do I stop css pushing <li> to the right?

Tags: html, css, layout, gallery, space

This is my first question and I'm having real difficulties sorting this problem.  Basically I have created a gallery using ul and li to make it responsive.  The gallery can be found here:

http://www.radiologycafe.com/radiology-trainees/normal-variants

The issue I'm having is that if the text underneath the image is too long, it pushes the image directly below to the right of the page.

How can I keep the images in a line whilst keeping the page responsive and avoiding the use of white-space:nowrap which causes the text to overlap with other text?!

Can anyone help me!?

[Screenshot of the problem.  I have drawn on (using amazing photoshop skills) how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq5yB.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1 (hide excess content to keep equal heights)

You can avoid this behavior by not allowing your `<h5>`s in your `<li>`s to wrap, using the CSS below. I also applied this rule to the descriptions (`<p>`s), in case you might add elements with longer descriptions in the future:

```
.nvgallery li h5, .nvgallery li p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/y7f5vakr/embedded/result/#Result)</kbd>
(Note: I didn't add all the CSS from your website, only the relevant parts for this issue).
If you want to display `inline-block` elements as grid, the condition is that all elements are equal in height. If one element is higher than the following ones, it will create a small floating point (a corner) where the browser will start a new (shorter) row.

### Solution 2 (allow unequal heights)

Flexbox.

```css
.nvgallery ul.row {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-moz-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
          flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/y7f5vakr/2/embedded/result/#Result)</kbd>
Now you can have li's of unequal heights and they will all play nicely.

Comment: Solution 2 would be ideal and works for PC browsers, however it does not display correctly on Safari on iPhone therefore I haven't implemented it.  Solution 1 is not ideal as it cuts short some of the text, however it looks good on all browsers so I have implemented solution 1.  I just changed the line-height to 1.4 as 1.2 was cutting off the bottom of the letter 'g'.  Many thanks

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue in Safari. Flexbox wrapping is not possible. The cost was huge for them in terms of mobile browser usage for this issue alone. Most of my friends are Apple customers and most of them  are currently using Chrome on their devices.

Comment: While searching for some browser hack to find an alternative for Safari (so you can use `flexbox`), I found an [online tool](http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/) pretending it supports `flex-wrap` in `Safari > 6.1`. Updated second solution but not able to test it. Let me know if it works. If they're right, `-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;` makes the difference.

Comment: Hi Andrei - I've tried implementing your new solution 2 but it still doesn't work on Safari - looks like it just doesn't work.  Solution 1 still pretty good though :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your list items have variable height. A quick fix would be to set a height of about 210px on each which should cover the added height from wrapped text:

```
.nvgallery ul li {
  height: 210px;
}
```

Test and adjust as needed.

The other fix, which is evidently necessary at first glance, is that your floats aren't clearing properly so that in some viewports the H3 tags end up appearing as though in-line with your images (which are floating to the left of the headlines).

If you set a rule to `clear:both` on H3, this problem is cleared up as well:

```
h3 {
  clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to edit your code so that it does not include { float: left; } on the li elements. Instead, try setting the li elements as inline blocks with { display: inline-block; }. You'll need to adjust the alignment of the li items a bit, but this should solve your issue.

An answer with JSFiddle sample code is available at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812316/5953701